# Error: sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on a small app which stores the place latitude and longitude in SQLite database. I have three classes as follows:

**AddPlaceActyivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.rememberthislocation.R;




public class AddPlaceActivity extends Activity{

    Button btn_remember,btn_maps;
    Fragment fr;
    Button addlocation;
    EditText locationname;
    String mylocationname,mylatitude,mylongitude;

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("my","In oncreateview");

        setContentView(R.layout.remember_fragment);


                addlocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_addlocation);
                 locationname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.locationname);


                  mylocationname = locationname.getText().toString();
                     Log.d("my","value 1 taken");

                    mylatitude = "0.0";
                    mylongitude = "0.0";

                      Log.d("my", "data values taken"); 


                  addlocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        MySqliteHelper db = new MySqliteHelper(getApplicationContext());

                        db.addPlaces(new Place(mylocationname,mylatitude,mylongitude));   

                    }
                });







        }






}
```

**MySqliteHelper.java**

```
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;

    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class MySqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static final String KEY_PLACENAME = "placename";
        private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
        private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";

        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "places";


        public MySqliteHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {



            //actual query = create table places (id primary key autoincrement, placename taxt, latitude real, longitude real);
               String query =  "CREATE TABLE" +TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_ID+
                        "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_PLACENAME+ 
                        "TEXT, "+KEY_LATITUDE+
                        "REAL, "+KEY_LONGITUDE+ "REAL)";

               try {
                    db.execSQL(query);
                    Log.d("my", "Successfully created table: " + query);
                } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   

        }



        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS places");

            this.onCreate(db);
        }


        public void addPlaces(Place place)
        {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues convalues = new ContentValues();



            convalues.put(KEY_PLACENAME,place.getname());
            convalues.put(KEY_LATITUDE,place.getlatitude());
            convalues.put(KEY_LONGITUDE,place.getlongitude());

              db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, convalues);
              Log.d("my","db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, convalues)");
              Log.d("my", "Values inserted");
              db.close();

        }




}
```

**Place.java**

```
public class Place {

    String mname,mlatitude,mlongitude,mstring;
    public Place(String name, String latitude, String longitude)
        {

          mname = name;
          mlatitude = latitude;
          mlongitude = longitude;


    }

    public Place() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setname(String placename)
    {
        mname = placename;


    }

    public String getname()
    {
        return mname;


    }

    public void setlatitude(String latitude)
    {
        mlatitude=latitude;


    }

    public String getlatitude()
    {
        return mlatitude;


    }


    public void setlongitude(String longitude)
    {
        mlongitude = longitude;


    }

    public String getlongitude()
    {
        return mlongitude;


    }
}
```

And my logcat log:

```
11-20 17:40:02.770: D/my(10604): In oncreateview
11-20 17:40:02.890: D/my(10604): acivity layout initialized
11-20 17:40:02.950: I/PGA(10604): New SOCKET connection: berthislocation (pid 10604, tid 10604)
11-20 17:40:16.510: D/my(11196): in remember's onclick
11-20 17:40:16.540: D/my(11196): intent started
11-20 17:40:16.560: D/my(11196): In oncreateview
11-20 17:40:16.560: D/my(11196): value 1 taken
11-20 17:40:16.560: D/my(11196): data values taken
11-20 17:40:27.290: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(11196): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: places, db=/data/data/com.example.rememberthislocation/databases/contactsManager
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196): Error inserting longitude=0.0 latitude=0.0 placename=
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: places: , while compiling: INSERT INTO places(longitude,latitude,placename) VALUES (?,?,?)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at com.example.rememberthisplace.MySqliteHelper.addPlaces(MySqliteHelper.java:74)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at com.example.rememberthisplace.AddPlaceActivity$1.onClick(AddPlaceActivity.java:52)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
11-20 17:40:27.290: E/SQLiteDatabase(11196):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Clearly the error is in MySqliteHelper.java

```
Error: sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: places
```

So, my  MySqliteHelper class's oncreate() isn't called. I tried for hours..but can't find the solution. Can anyone help me?

Comment: where you create table places ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana  in Helper class : String query =  "CREATE TABLE" +TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_ID+
                        "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_PLACENAME+ 
                        "TEXT, "+KEY_LATITUDE+
                        "REAL, "+KEY_LONGITUDE+ "REAL)";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have bugs in your `onCreate()` that are hidden by the `catch`:

```
String query =  "CREATE TABLE" +TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_ID+
                    "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_PLACENAME+ 
                    "TEXT, "+KEY_LATITUDE+
                    "REAL, "+KEY_LONGITUDE+ "REAL)";
```

Missing whitespace, change to:

```
String query =  "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_ID+
                    " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_PLACENAME+ 
                    " TEXT, "+KEY_LATITUDE+
                    " REAL, "+KEY_LONGITUDE+ " REAL)";
```

Remove the try-catch. If there's a problem, the framework should be thrown an exception. If `onCreate()` returns normally, the framework thinks the database was set up successfully. `onCreate()` is only called once when the database is first set up.

Uninstall your app or clear its data to get rid of the old empty database file and to get `onCreate()` rerun.

Further reading: [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Comment: why oncreate is hidden by catch? i mean every time, it throws an explicit exception?!